Error ''Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'canvas')'' while creating a pixi.js app
I am getting the error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'canvas') while trying to run a  pixi.js app. Here is my code :
 <script src = 'js/pixi.min.js'></script>
 <script>

       let app;
       window.onload = function() {
       app = new PIXI.Application(
          {
              width: 800,
              height: 600,
              backgroundColor: 0xAAAAAA
          }
          );
       document.body.appendChild(app.view);
    }; 

</script>

I am using pixi.js version 8. This error specifically comes from app.view. Why am I getting this error?
It seems to have worked for other people so I don't why it isn't for me.

Your own script probably runs before pixi is loaded. Can you try <script defer>your code </script>

I'd prefer not do that. I have a lot of code so I just put my javascript code in a separate file and then use a  tag to 'import' the code to my html file.

You'll need to make sure PIXI is loaded before your code runs, for example. <script defer src="yourcode.js"></script>. If you don't want to use the defer keyword you can use addEventListener("load") in your script to see if PIXI is loaded. And if you want to use import you will have to use modules :)

Okay. Thank you!
